# Mysql: Adding random row in table with many FOREIGN KEY's

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is a method which can add new row to the table that has many foreign key's, row columns can be random.

***I want to create element in table with recurzion on references. Let imagin case: all tables are empty, and I have table (MAIN) with many references to other tables, and all references table have their own references.***
So is it possible to create element in (MAIN) and with the same time all dependent elements that are needed for the insert action on (MAIN) by passing references keys in the element creation in (MAIN).

Comment: Short answer `Yes`  there is a method. Long Answer show us some sample data and schema to work with.

Comment: I have added explanations.

Comment: doesnt ogres answer solve your issue?

Comment: What if FK_ONE_TABLE has no elements and have references to other table. Is it possible to create elements with recurzion?

Comment: Can you write an example? or maybe another question?

Comment: I will change my question so that its more clear.

Comment: You say you want recursion but you dont explain what kind of recursion

Comment: Is this a little more clear? Its really hard to explain because I don't know what is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94237/discussion-between-urosjarc-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: If I understand it right the short answer is **NO** you can't do that with a sql command. You can do it with a trigger or a function though.

Comment: Well I didn't think with simple command but maybe with some function?

Answer (score 1):

You can select random ID from foreign-key-table and use that,

example :

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE 
    (fk_one,fk_two) 
VALUES 
    ( 
    (SELECT id from FK_ONE_TABLE order by  rand() limit 1),
    (SELECT id from FK_TWO_TABLE order by  rand() limit 1) 
    )
```

Online example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47d54/1

Comment: This is really nice to know that you can pass values (im kinda rooky in mysql). I want to ask if its possible to create FK_ONE_TABLE element and what if FK_ONE_TABLE have refrence to other table? The creation has to have recurzion, is this possible?

Comment: yes , you would do it step by step, first create tables then add keys and insert random numbers